# Why set arrayLength in "new Array(arrayLength)"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example:

`array1 = new Array(5); array2 = new Array(10);`

Both `console.log(array1)` and `console.log(array2)` would return `[]`. 
then, what is the role of arrayLength here?

Comment: console.log() conceals details by making things pretty, they are not the same. sometimes it's faster to pre-size the array. usually it doesn't matter much and to be sure, arrays are expandable at any time.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript hides a lot of the details that you'd typically have to deal with when working with arrays in many other languages. For example, an array in JavaScript can grow automatically as you push values to it.

However, under the covers, the runtime is still dealing with the same sort of memory allocation issues that languages like C or Java make visible to the developer. The runtime may set aside a little extra memory for the array to grow into, and then once it runs out of contiguous memory space, it'll reallocate a larger piece of memory somewhere else and copy all of the values from the first set of memory to another location.

(This is vastly oversimplifying things, but hopefully you get the general idea.)

If you know ahead of time exactly how many items you can expect to put into the array, using `new Array(number)` will give the runtime a hint that it can begin by allocating that much memory, and avoid the need for the memory to be reallocated and copied around as you grow it.

It's in this light, for example, that [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/#toc-topic-numbers) suggests the following practices to achieve maximum performance in the V8 javascript engine:

- Don't pre-allocate large Arrays (e.g. > 64K elements) to their maximum size, instead grow as you go
- Initialize using array literals for small fixed-sized arrays
- Preallocate small arrays (<64k) to correct size before using them

Answer (score 1):

Passing a number to the `Array` constructor sets the length property of the array without setting the indices of the items (which is why your `console.log` isn't showing anything).

To quote [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#array.constructor):

> Being able to set the length of the array in advance is only useful in a few cases, like repeating a string, in which it avoids the use of a loop.

Here's an example of doing just that:

```
new Array(count + 1).join(stringToRepeat);
```

Comment: The fact that it sets the `.length` property is definitely an important point. Thanks for mentioning that.